# Android pop-up login screen with WebView

Tags: android, authentication, webview, android-webview

I am opening up a `webpage` using `WebView` that extends `WebChromeClient`.

The page has pop-up for login, as pictured here.
[image]

When I use the `setWebViewClient`, it just prompts me white screen so my guess is that it does not support `Authentication`. When I tried creating custom `WebViewClient`, I found that it has a method called `onReceivedHttpAuthRequest` which I think is the correct place, but how do I display the pop-up on screen?

```
public class BaseWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

public enum SpinnerMode {
    ALWAYS,
    FIRST,
    DISABLED
}

private final CoordinatorLayout webViewContainer;
private final RelativeLayout progressBarOverlay;

private WeakReference<BaseWebViewActivity> activityRef;
private BaseWebViewStateRemover stateRemover = new BaseWebViewStateRemover();

private boolean isFirstPage = true;
private SpinnerMode spinnerMode;

public BaseWebViewClient(BaseWebViewActivity activity, CoordinatorLayout container, RelativeLayout progressBarOverlay, SpinnerMode spinnerMode) {
    this.activityRef = new WeakReference<BaseWebViewActivity>(activity);
    this.webViewContainer = container;
    this.progressBarOverlay = progressBarOverlay;
    this.spinnerMode = spinnerMode != null ? spinnerMode : SpinnerMode.DISABLED;
}

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    Logger.e("onReceivedSslError: " + (error != null ? error.toString() : "null"));
    BaseWebViewActivity activity = activityRef.get();
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
    }
    super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(final WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    BaseWebViewActivity context = this.activityRef.get();
    if(context != null) {
        stateRemover.removeStateOnLogoutRequestMatch(context, request, view, webViewContainer);
    } else {
        Logger.w("Cannot remove app session context fully, activity reference is null");
    }
    return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
}

@Override
public void onPageStarted(final WebView webView, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    super.onPageStarted(webView, url, favicon);
    Logger.d("Webview loading started for URL " + filterHashFragment(url));

    if (spinnerMode == SpinnerMode.ALWAYS
            || spinnerMode == SpinnerMode.FIRST && isFirstPage) {
        progressBarOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(final WebView webView, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(webView, url);
    Logger.d("Webview loading finished for URL " + filterHashFragment(url));

    if (spinnerMode == SpinnerMode.ALWAYS
            || spinnerMode == SpinnerMode.FIRST && isFirstPage) {
        // Add short delay because onPageFinished triggers often a bit early causing the
        // previous page to be briefly shown.
        SystemClock.sleep(150);
        Activity activity = activityRef.get();
        if(activity != null) {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressBarOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
        } else {
            Logger.w("activity is not available");
        }
    }

    if (isFirstPage)
        isFirstPage = false;
}

private String filterHashFragment(String url) {
    return url.split("#")[0];
}

}
```

ChromeClient (it never reaches the onJsAlert)

```
public class BaseWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
private WeakReference<BaseWebViewActivity> activityRef;

public BaseWebChromeClient(BaseWebViewActivity activity) {
    this.activityRef = new WeakReference<BaseWebViewActivity>(activity);
}

@Override
public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
    Log.i("js console: ",   cm.message() + " -- line "
            + cm.lineNumber() + " of "
            + cm.sourceId());
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
    Log.i("testing123", "got js alert");

    return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
}
}
```

And I call Webview here:

```
    webView = findViewById(R.id.baseWebView);
    webViewContainer = findViewById(R.id.webview_container);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new BaseWebChromeClient(this));
    webView.setWebViewClient(new BaseWebViewClient(this, webViewContainer,
            (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.progressBarOverlay), getSpinnerMode(intent)));
```

If that is not possible then maybe it is possible to create a custom login scren when the login button is clicked. But when creating the custom screen, then how can I send the `login details (username/password)` to the `WebViewClient` and how to get the response from there etc.

**EDIT!!**

Added my custom client code.

When giving the username and password to `onReceivedHttpAuthRequest` like this

```
@Override
public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, final HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
    handler.proceed("username", "password");
}
```

The application logs in and continues as it should. When I give wrong credentials, the applications gives me an error `Web page not available`, `net::ERR_TOO_MANY_RETRIES` and when I give nothing I just see an empty white screen.

Comment: Please post the URL here to test

Comment: Added my own answer. Do you still want to try it?

Comment: So now what is happening when you enter wrong credentials

Comment: The dialog will reset and ask again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to count the retry's and to prompt a new login dialog on every  `onReceivedHttpAuthRequest` in `WebView` client.

```
@Override
public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, final HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
    httpAuthRequestCounter++;
    if (httpAuthRequestCounter < 2) {
        alertDialog(handler);
        httpAuthRequestCounter = 0;
    } else {
        handler.cancel();
        goBackToLoginScreen();
    }
}

private void alertDialog(final HttpAuthHandler httpAuthHandler) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(baseWebViewActivity);
    LayoutInflater inflater = baseWebViewActivity.getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_dialog, null);

    final EditText txtUsername = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dauth_userinput);
    final EditText txtPassword = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dauth_passinput);

    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    httpAuthHandler.proceed(txtUsername.getText().toString(), txtPassword.getText().toString());
                }
            }
    );
    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    httpAuthHandler.cancel();
                    goBackToLoginScreen();

                }
            }
    );

    dialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this url overriding other url that contains this popup. From your question this popup is coming from main url not your custom. So in your webChromeClient you have to use below code.

```
@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
```

This will help you to show the popup.

For enabling JS pop up use below code.

```
 @Override
     public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
    //Required functionality here
   return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
  }
```

And make sure you enable javascript Enable in your web view:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true)
```

Comment: This did not work, added my custom client code, maybe that will help to understand what is wrong here.

Comment: I have a class that extends `WebChromeClient` and that has the `onJsAlert` in it. But it when checking from logs if it gets there then I found that it never even gets to that part. Other things that you mentioned I already have.

Comment: If you miss below things you can add.

webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

Comment: I wish that worked but it seems that it does not.. added all of them but ` webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true)`, because it did not find it

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the fact that it never reaches the `onJsAlert` in my `ChromeClient` ?